# Can I manually lock a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have multiple independent processes, Scripts A and B, that each access the same table.  I would like to Script A to read a record from the table then maybe modify that record (or maybe not).

The thing is that I need to keep Script B from accessing that particular record In the midst of that.  Is there a manual lock perhaps?  Something that will keep Script B out for just those few milliseconds?

Thanks

Comment: Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya:  You should make that an answer.

Comment: @wallyk it is most likely a duplicate

Comment: Don't forget about transaction isolation level and storage engine involved too

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to lock the entire table right?

For InnoDB table a [`select...for update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) should do, it will lock the record (just add `for update` at the end of the query).

On your script A:

1. Create a transaction
2. Do a select for update
3. If you want to update the record, do so.
4. Commit the transaction when you finish.

On your script B do a select for update as well, it will wait until script A release the lock.